# Вывод бинарного дерева

Tags: c++, структуры, бинарное-дерево

Как мне вывести бинарное дерево красиво. Ну или хотя бы чтобы было похоже на дерево.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int field;// поле данных
    struct Node* left;// левый потомок
    struct Node* right;// правый потомок
};

struct Node* addnode(int x, Node* tree) { //Функция добавления узла
    if (tree == NULL) { // Если дерева нет, то формируем корень
        tree = new Node; // память под узел
        tree->field = x; 
        tree->left = NULL;
        tree->right = NULL; // ветви инициализируем пустотой
    }
    else  if (x < tree->field)  // условие добавление левого потомка
        tree->left = addnode(x, tree->left);
    else    // условие добавление правого потомка
        tree->right = addnode(x, tree->right);
    return(tree);
}

void TreePrint(Node* tree) {//Функция вывода данных узла
    if (tree != NULL) { 
        cout <<" ["<< tree->field<<"] "; //корень дерева
        TreePrint(tree->left); //левое поддерево
        TreePrint(tree->right); //правое поддерево
    }
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");
    struct Node* root = NULL;    // Объявляем структуру дерева
    int a,n;
    cout << "Введите кол-во узлов = ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите узел " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> a;
        root = addnode(a, root);
    }
    TreePrint(root);    // выводим элементы дерева, получаем отсортированный массив
    cin.get();  cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте смещение от начала строки, а каждый узел выводите в отдельной строке

```cpp
void TreePrint(Node* tree, int padding = 0) {//Функция вывода данных узла
    if (tree != NULL) {
        //корень дерева
        cout << setw(padding) << ' ' << setw(0) << " ["<< tree->field<<"] " << endl;
        padding += 2;
        TreePrint(tree->left, padding); //левое поддерево
        TreePrint(tree->right, padding); //правое поддерево
    }
}
```